# How to delete blank cells of the column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I am trying to get rid of the blank cells of the column in my sheet. I get some data from my colleagues via Google Form, and I have made some subcategory questions for them. So they get to select one of the five given choices. When I export the data to the sheet, it appears somewhat like below (linked):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DBrFFNst0nhZAtxHejsrbNGkMxvcbOuie47era0Hl8c/edit?usp=sharing

Because the users can select one choice, out of five given choices four other cells must be left empty. Here's where I'm struggling with:
I have used filter function to get rid of the blank cells, but then it is restricted to only set the range either single row or column. So I end up with what you would see in my sample worksheet.

I've tried arrayformula and query as well, but I couldn't figure out a way out of this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({B1:G7, {"subcategory"; TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(H2:L7),,999^99)))}})
```

[image: 0]

Comment: It works very well. I appreciate your help. Thank you!